# Category of Field has no initial object

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, category-theory

Why the category of **Field** has no initial object?

(see page $47$ of *Category Theory* by Horst Herrlich and George E. Strecker )

Comment: Think about what the characteristic of an initial object must be.

Comment: Since there are no maps between fields of different characteristic, it is not very useful to lump them all together into a single category.

Comment: If there were a field that mapped into all finite fields, what kind of problems might you have (especially since all those maps must be injective)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Note that in the category of all fields, given any field $\mathbf{F}$ there is always a different field $\mathbf{K}$ such that there are no field homomorphisms from $\mathbf{F}$ to $\mathbf{K}$ nor from $\mathbf{K}$ to $\mathbf{F}$. Therefore, there can be neither an initial nor a terminal object (because the former requires maps *into* every object, and the latter requires maps *from* every object).

And the reason this happens is that there can be no field homomorphisms between fields of different characteristics.

Now, if you change to the category of $\mathbf{Field}_{p}$, where $p$ is either a prime or $0$, and this is the category of all fields of characteristic $p$, then this category *does* have an initial object, namely the prime field of characteristic $p$: $\mathbf{F}_p$ for $p\gt 0$, and $\mathbb{Q}$ for $p=0$.

Comment: Is there a nice functor from $\mathbf{Field}_p\to\mathbf{Field}_{p+1}$ that takes $\mathbb{F}_p$ to $\mathbb{F}_{p+1}$, and you could somehow (ignoring cardinality and universe issues) form the category of fields of characteristic zero as the colimit of these categories (I'm not even sure we have colimits in $\mathbf{Cat}$).

Comment: @JBeardz First, I assume you mean somehow go from $\mathbf{Field}_{p(k)}$ to $\mathbf{Field}_{p(k+1)}$, where $p(k)$ is the $k$th prime? (Otherwise, that only makes sense for $p=2$...).  I don't think so, but I could be wrong. Note, though, that you *can* construct fields of characteristic zero with fields of finite characteristic: if you take a nontrivial ultraproduct of all the prime fields of positive characteristic, then you get a field of characteristic zero... (this was one of the questions in my Oral Qualifying...)

Comment: Thanks Arturo, yeah that's what I meant. Interesting.