# Free object in the category of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I've seen this stated on this site as well as elsewhere that there is no free object in the category of fields on a set $X$ of any size including the empty set. I'm wondering why this is the case?

Comment: what have you tried? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81458/category-of-field-has-no-initial-object might be of some use

Comment: You should play around with the concept, as @PraphullaKoushik hints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Assume $F$ is a free field on the set $X$. Then try to extend any map $X\to K$ to a homomorphism where $K$ has different characteristic.

Comment: What about the category of fields of a given characteristic?